RowExpand event not working properly in RadzenDataGrid
I tried to fetch the actual expanded / collapsed state of an RadzenDataGrid by attaching to the RowExpand-Event.
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="grid" RowExpand="RowExpanded" .../>
<Template>
...
</Template>
<Columns>
...
</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

....

void RowExpanded(ItemType item)
{
//OpenRow = item.id;
}

By debugging I am able to see that my event get`s triggered succesfully. But even if the event doesn't do anything at all it breaks the functionality of the RadzenDataGrid, so that the details view doesn't get opened at all. If I remove the RowExpand-handler the RadzenDataGrid works as usually again.
Any ideas about that. In the online-demo of Radzen everything works fine, but I don't see any difference compared to my own code.
Edit:
Thanks for your feedback, please see the following simplified sample for reproducing the issue.
Model:
public class Testmodel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Testmodel(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

Blazor:
@page "/Testseite"
<h3>Testpage</h3>


    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" AllowSorting="true" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single" Data="@Datasets" TItem="Testmodel" RowExpand="RowExpand">
        <Template Context="ModelDetail">
            <RadzenStack>
                <RadzenText>Id: @ModelDetail.Id</RadzenText>
                <RadzenText>Name: @ModelDetail.Name</RadzenText>
            </RadzenStack>
        </Template>
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Testmodel" Property="Id" Title="Id" Filterable="true" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Testmodel" Property="Name" Title="Name" Filterable="true" />
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>


    @if(SelectedId.HasValue)
    {
        <RadzenText>SelectedId: @SelectedId.Value</RadzenText>
    }

@code {
    RadzenDataGrid<Testmodel> grid;
    int? SelectedId = null;

    private List<Testmodel> Datasets
    {
        get
        {
            List<Testmodel> models = new List<Testmodel>();
            models.Add(new Testmodel(1, "ABC"));
            models.Add(new Testmodel(2, "DEF"));
            models.Add(new Testmodel(3, "XYZ"));
            return models;
        }
    }


    void RowExpand(Testmodel model)
    {
        SelectedId = model.Id;
    }

   

}


I didn't see triggering the event break functionality. Could you provider a small sample code to reproduce this?

Hello @QiangFu: I just edited my code to provide the requested sample code

I don't know why use the getter to set the value but if you assign values like following the functionality works normally:
    private List<Testmodel> Datasets = new List<Testmodel>
    {
           new Testmodel { Id = 1, Name = "ABC" },
           new Testmodel { Id = 2, Name = "DEF" },
           new Testmodel { Id = 3, Name = "XYZ" }
    };


Hello Qiang Fu,
the property was there because later the data will be coming from a database. I tried a bit and found that the property itself doesn't seems to be the issue, but the fact, that I'm creating new instances when the property is called. But the main question is: Why does it makes an difference if I'm subscribing to the RowExpand-event? Because without subscribing to that event the RadzenDataGrid seems to be fine with the property / new instance...

Based from the hint from @QiangFu I did a bit more research. It seems to me, that the DatGrid requeries the database on expanding and isn't able to identify the new and the old instance to be the same dataset. It seems to work if equals() and GetHash() are overriden to identify the datasets by it's id.
public override bool Equals(object? obj)
{
    var OtherObjekt = obj as Testmodel;

    if (OtherObjekt != null)
    {
        if ((Id != null) && (OtherObjekt.Id != null))
        {
            if (Id == OtherObjekt.Id)
            {
                return true; ;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return base.Equals(obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (Id != 0)
    {
        return Id;
    }
    return base.GetHashCode();
}

Nevertheless it is still not clear to me, why this is only relevant in case the RowExpand event is subscribed. Maybe someone else is able to tell if this is just a bug in RadzenDataGrid or if there is a serious reason for this behavior.

Update: I think the new request to the datasource is created through the fact, that the event has the displayed item itself as argument
